# Display Results of API call in a PHP form field - Postcode & Suburb

Tags: php, api, curl

I have seen this done many times but don't know how its done? When a user enters their postcode in a form field and tabs off the field, the Suburb field is then populated with a list of suburbs that match the postcode. I know that if I store the postcodes and suburbs in a database table it would be easy. However I have an API that I can use from Australia Post that is the most up to date and accurate. Has anyone had to develop something similar that they can share? I have tried doing this via PHP and cURL. I get the results of the API call successfully but don't know how to display in the form field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to make an AJAX call to a script which handles working with the API.  The results need to be parsed with JavaScript and dynamically populated into a predesignated area on the page.  Or the PHP script can itself form the exact HTML for all the results so no parsing is necessary at the JavaScript level (I prefer this way, personally).

Assuming you want each of those city results to be clickable (so that the city name then appears in an input box when clicked), you'll need to set up a listener on the page that'll detect what's been clicked and the city name it represents, and then place that city name into the form field where it should go.

I don't know how far along you are, so in case you've already got the AJAX down, here's an example jQuery listener that'll take the contents (a city name) of a dynamically-populated element that appears after an AJAX call, with class name city_results, and then stick the name into an input box elsewhere on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".city_results").click(function() {
    city_name = $(this).html();
    $("input[name=INPUT_BOX_NAME]").val(city_name);
});
</script>
```

Replace INPUT_BOX_NAME with the name given to the input element for city name.

This listener would be activated anytime a div like this is clicked by the user:

```
<div class="city_results">Melbourne</div>
```

Hope this gets you started.